# Django - How to fix multiple pks in url?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-templates

I currently have a live search functionality built out mostly working how I want.

**Functionality works like this:**

A user searches a word on the search bar.

Then the user gets a display of suggested searches that includes text and an image.

The user clicks on the text/image from the suggested searches that they want and then the user goes to the template page that includes the primary key in the url.

**The Problem:**

When the user is on the template page that includes the primary key and another form submission is made. An additional pk gets added to the URL.

**Example:**

http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/2/

This results in Page Not Found 404.

How do i fix this? After a user makes another submission I just need the url updated with the new primary key.

So this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/2/ needs to be this http://127.0.0.1:8000/2/

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Code Below:**

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', account_view_home, name='home'),

    # Below are the urls where the live search is enabled #
    path ('game_details/', search_results_view, name="game_details"),    
    path ('<pk>/', search_detail_view, name="detail")

]
```

**views.py**

```
def search_detail_view(request,pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Game_Info, id=pk)
    user_prices = Shopping_Prices.objects.all()
    game_leaderboard = User_Info.objects.all()

    # return render(request, 'detail.html', {'obj':obj})
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_profile = User_Info.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        context = {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'user_prices': user_prices,
            'game_leaderboard': game_leaderboard,
            'obj': obj
        }

    else:
        context = {
            'user_prices': user_prices,
            'game_leaderboard': game_leaderboard,
            'obj': obj
       }
    return render(request, "detail.html", context)


def search_results_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        res = None
        game = request.POST.get('game')
        print(game)
        qs = Game_Info.objects.filter(game_title__icontains=game).order_by('game_title')[:4]
        if len(qs) > 0 and len(game) > 0:
            data = []
            for pos in qs:
                item ={
                    'pk': pos.pk,
                    'name': pos.game_title,
                    'game_provider': pos.game_provider,
                    'image': str(pos.game_image.url)
                }
                data.append(item)
            res = data
        else:
            res = 'No games found...'

        return JsonResponse({'data': res})
    return JsonResponse({})
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    const url = window.location.href
    const searchForm = document.getElementById("search-form");
    const searchInput = document.getElementById("search_input_field");

    const resultsBox = document.getElementById("results-box");
    const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
    console.log(csrf)

    const sendSearchData = (game) =>{
        $.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/game_details/',

            data: {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf,
                'game' : game,
            },
            success: (res)=> {
                console.log(res.data)
                const data = res.data
                if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                    resultsBox.innerHTML = `<div class="row-tw"><h1>Recommended Games</h1></div>`
                    data.forEach(game=> {
                        resultsBox.innerHTML += `                    
                            <a href="${url}${game.pk}" class="item" >                          
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2">
                                        <img src="${game.image}" class="game-img">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>${game.name}</p>
                                        <span class="game-pub-title">${game.game_provider}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        `
                    })
                } else {
                   if (searchInput.value.length > 0) {
                    resultsBox.innerHTML = `<h2>${data}</h2>`
                   } else {
                    resultsBox.classList.add('not-visible')
                   }
                }
            },
            error: (err)=> {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    }

    searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', e=> {
           if (resultsBox.classList.contains('not-visible')) {
            resultsBox.classList.remove('not-visible')
        }
        sendSearchData(e.target.value)
    })

});
```

**HTML**

```
                    <form method="POST" autocomplete="off" id="search-form" action="{% url 'search_results' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="search_input_field" type="text" name="q" autocomplete="off" class="form-control gs-search-bar" placeholder="Search Games..." value="">
                            <div id="results-box" class="results-card not-visible"></div>
                            <span class="search-clear">x</span>
                            <button id="search_btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary search-button" disabled>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-search"></i>
                                </span> 
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Build and return the url in your search function. Then just use it with yout js code.

Comment: How would I do that with my current code? I'm a little lost. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build and return the url directly via your view:

```
from django.urls import reverse

def search_results_view(request):
    ...
            for pos in qs:
                item ={
                    'pk': pos.pk,
                    'name': pos.game_title,
                    'game_provider': pos.game_provider,
                    'image': str(pos.game_image.url),
                    'url': reverse('detail', args=[pos.pk]),
                }
                data.append(item)
    ...
```

Then use the `url` directly in you js success method:

```
<a href="${game.url}" class="item" >
```

Comment: Thank You! That worked perfectly! You're a ninja! May you have a great day today :)